# Footer overlaps on carousel

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, less, struts

Ok, so I've inherited some code, and when I shrink the window to the smallest size, the footer (which is in position: absolute) overlaps with the body (which is divided in a vertical carousel (one per page, 4 pages).
structure is something like:

```
<body>
  <navbar> Content </navbar>
  <div class="some-carousel">
    <carousel-data></carousel-data>
    <footer style="position: absolute;"></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

So each of the 4 carousel pages spans the whole window, and the last page has a footer at the bottom. 
When the window is minimised, because the carousel page still takes over the whole page, the footer overlaps some elements. Is it possible, to push the footer to the bottom, even when the carousel takes over the page? (make it scrollable even)

its build in struts and most of the styling is quite convoluted (inline, on page, and in .css files) so I can't really link the code directly because its a bit everywhere... sorry :(

Comment: AFAICT Struts is completely irrelevant and it's purely a CSS issue. Not sure how to help.

Comment: thanks for looking at it regardless, its appreciated :) I can link to the website that I inherited is that would help? 
www.bizbizshare.com

Comment: This appears to be by design--if you have elements popping up based on scroll position you either need to add some space to the carousel or do something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/16244821/438992